# Reloading the view when row changed in tableview objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, drawing, drawable, draw

I have done markup code for different images. When the image changes, the markup and button still remain on screen. only it changes when i make a new markup on it.

The below image shows the button and markup of beach image.

Please help me...

[image]

Comment: Try call setNeedsDisplay on the view where you placed the markup (after you remove it) this should force UIView to redraw itself.

Comment: @Greg i have called [self setNeedDisplay] method but its not working... I am calling tableview function in one class and these markup and button in other class

Comment: Show the code where you add and remove the markup and buttons.

Comment: @Greg the code which i have used is working fine like i am getting markup count and removing the button. only thing is in displaying

Answer (score 0):

You might be using viewController.view instead of inhering UIView.

So now you can call a viewcontroller's instance method on `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` event, which will clear all the widgets from the existing view.

```
- (void)clearSubviewsFromContainerView
{
   for(UIView *view in [containerView subviews])
   {
       [view removeFromSuperview];
   }

   [self createNewWidgets];
}
```

Then call another method to generate and load new widgets.

```
- (void)createNewWidgets 
{
   // add new buttons, images over here in the same container view
}
```

Hope this might help you out.